# NZEC error on SPOJ- http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I am again and again getting the NZEC(Non Zero Exit Code) error for this problem while the code works perfectly fine on my PC.Please help. I think the problem is with the input code using the class BufferedReader. My code is:-

```
import java.io.*;
class Prime1
{
public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
{
int count=0;
System.out.println("Enter the number of test cases");
BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
int T=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
for(int i=1;i<=T;i++)
{
    System.out.println("Enter the value of m and n such that 1<=m<=n<=1000000000");
    BufferedReader br1= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int m=Integer.parseInt(br1.readLine());
    BufferedReader br2= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int n=Integer.parseInt(br2.readLine());
    for(int j=m;j<=n;j++)
    {
        for(int k=1;k<=j;k++)
        {
            if(j%k==0)
            count++;
        }
        if(count==2)
        System.out.println(j);
        count=0;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
}
}
```

Comment: NZEC isn't a real Java error. Instead of making us guess as to what your problem submission website means by that error, tell us exactly the stacktrace or what the error is actually reported asl.

Comment: And what the fhell iz NZEC?

Comment: NZEC stands for Non Zero Exit Code.

Comment: 5. RE - runtime error -
NZEC (non-zero exit code) - this message means that the program exited returning a value different from 0 to the shell. For languages such as C, this probably means you forgot to add "return 0" at the end of the program. For interpreted languages (including JAVA) NZEC will usually mean that your program either crashed or raised an uncaught exception.
other - there are other signals which can cause program to terminate, all the remaining ones are simply displayed as other.

Comment: NZEC stands for Non Zero Exit Code.On running this code it gives an error in the main method.While the program compiles properly.I've explained the NZEC error in the previous comment as well.

Answer (score 2):

Do not print statements like this:

```
System.out.println("Enter the number of test cases");
```

Solutions are checked automatically and any extra output will be treated as wrong answer.

Your program doesn't work for input separated by spaces. Try using `Scanner` to read input. For example:

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int T = in.nextInt();
    for (int i = 1; i <= T; i++) {
        int m = in.nextInt();
        int n = in.nextInt();
    ...
```

Comment: Sir, what is the problem if I try to take the input using the BufferedReader class?

Comment: You are creating multiple buffered readers. Each will keep some input in a buffer, characters in that buffer will be lost. Moreover, `readLine` will read whole line, this won't work for numbers separated by spaces.

Comment: If you enter exactly the input from example, you will see those errors. See [here](http://ideone.com/EWZ7p3) and [here](http://ideone.com/apleuQ).

Comment: Thank you Sir, @Banthar. I wonder if BufferedReader can accept spaces as input.?

Comment: However, on accepting the input with the scanner class it gives the Time Limit Exceeded error.

Comment: You can use readLine but you will have to split the numbers separated by space. For example: `String[] mn = br.readLine().split(" "); int m = Integer.parseInt(mn[0])`. It's possible you just need faster algorithm to avoid TLE.